# Dart stream listen not working as expected

Tags: dart, stream

Using a dart stream for the 1st time.  In the following code, while stepping through it in VSCODE, jumps from the tranform result to the final bracket.  It appears to not execute any of the listen callbacks.  How do I resolve this?

```
Future<void> addListsFileToDb(File file) async {
file.openRead().transform(utf8.decoder).listen(
    (String value) => print(value),
    onError: (error) => print(error),
    onDone: () => print("done"));}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streams (like futures) are asynchronous. When you call `listen`, you tell the stream to start working, and set up some callbacks to get called when the stream has a value available ... and then it's done.

*Later*, potentially much later depending on what the stream is doing, the stream will have generated its first value. At that point it will generate a data event, which will call the data callback/handler (here `(String value) => print(value)`).
Until then, program execution continues normally, so skipping to the end of the `listen` call immediately is correct and expected behavior, the `listen` call completes immediately and doesn't call any of the callbacks yet.

Comment: Thank you.  It turns out that in order to see the print output to my debug console in VSCode, I needed to add a break in the callback.  I was expecting the print output to still print to the console even without me placing a break in the callback.